# ngStorage [$injector:modulerr] Error

Tags: angularjs

I did the following in the code:

angular-core.js:

```
var jdi = angular.module('jdi', ['ngStorage']);
```

login.html:

```
<!-- Angular -->
<script src="/assets/vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/angular/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendor/angular/angular-loader.js"></script>
```

it gives me the error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=jdi&p1=Error%3A%20…2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fassets%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)
```

I'm new to angular, can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here?

Comment: where is the resource for `ngStorage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular could not inject a module you required. Here, the only module from your code sample is ngStorage, and from `login.html` it seems that you did not load ngStorage javascript; if it is ngStorage from https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage, you should have something like

```
<script src="/assets/vendor/ngstorage/ngStorage.min.js"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was stupid in forgetting to include that. This helps